# Error when creating Rally app skeleton

Tags: rally

I want to create custom rally app to pull up defect dashboard from certain  epic/stories in rally. Below are the step that I followed :
1. install ruby 193
2. install - gem install rake
2.1 downloaded starter kit
3. install gem install jslint-v8 
I got error  about missing libv8 
I did some research online and  installed python27. but still getting similar error . and not able to run rake new[AppName]

Appreciate your help in advance !

Comment: I ask since old versions of that Rake file used the V8 Gem for jslint. That gem doesn't work on Windows which could be the cause of your problem.

Comment: Yes I'm using windows. is there a work around for Windows OS?

Answer (score 0):

If you feel daring you can also try my Node.js tool for building Apps. I am creating it to be a seamless upgrade for users of the Rakefile. It should be more Windows friendly when I get it completed. Eventually I hope to add some great features for App testing into the builder.If you feel like checking out rally-app-builder the GitHub repo for it is right [here](http://goo.gl/A3PKV).

In it's current state it has most of the same functionality as the Rakefile.